# WP Custom tables query

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, customization, shortcode

I returned to PHP / MySQL development after a long break, and I am working on a project that requires some customization.
First, I added a credentials file; then I am referencing that file in my test file to query the custom tables I have in the DB.
This seems to work fine, but now I don't want to build custom code for each query I need since I have a dozen custom tables.
Ideally, I want to call a function to which I pass the SQL query and get the result.
I also want to display the output in a field or table (depending on the output) in an Elementor widget.
Is this the right way to think? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: There is a custom class already for this purpose: `$wpdb->`.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/  So you just keep reusing that and you can use whatever modifications of the queries you like.  As for the output into Elementor, you'll need to build your own Elementor widget (I think, I've never done it.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ehh I am new here. What shall I do?